# How do I emulate N900 hardware? (armel, OMAP3)

Tags: debian, qemu

Is it possible to emulate the Nokia N900 hardware on my laptop for development purposes? I've had a look at some emulators, and Googled, but I can't find anything relevant.

I know there's the Maemo SDK, but I'm not using Maemo. My long term goal is to compile my own distro based on Arch for the N900, but I have some learning to do, which is why I require an emulator. At least that way I can safely break the emulator.

I know the N900 is an armel architecture: Texas Instruments OMAP3 microprocessor with the ARM Cortex-A8 core.

I have a feeling this is Quemu related, but I don't know where to start.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to write software in C for N900? It may be easier to use Python, Perl or something similar if it's possible to install them on the hardware.

Comment: Yes, I will be using C. I generally create my scripts using Python on the N900, but that requires Maemo. What I'm looking to do is build my own kernel for education, and learning.

Comment: To what extent do you want to emulate the hardware? Are you just looking for an arm processor, or do you want to emulate all the hardware peripherals as well (touchscreen, accelerometer, …)?